# MaterializeCSS tooltip text vanishes on mobile

Tags: javascript, css, materialize

I have implemented a [MaterializeCSS tooltip](http://materializecss.com/dialogs.html). The `tooltip` is triggered whenever a specific text phrase is hovered over. It works great on desktop, but imperfectly on mobile.

What happens is that when the phrase is touched / clicked on (via iOS) the `tooltip 'box'` appears, but the text vanishes after briefly appearing. The `tooltip 'box'` continues to appear until the user touches / clicks away.

Essentially, the bug is the vanishing text. I naturally want the text to remain in the box until the user touches / clicks away.

I added the following **css** to ensure that the `tooltip` works on desktop. This code also ensures that the `tooltip 'box'` disappears when the user clicks / touches away:

```
body { 
    cursor: pointer;    
}
```

I added this as it was initially advised [here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/16028), although a later poster correctly pointed out this method might cause other quirks, such as the one I'm seeing.

The **HTML** for the tooltip is:

```
<a class = "tool tipped light" data-position="bottom" data-delay="100" data-tooltip="here be the tooltip!">
    the text to hover over
</a>
```

**So in a sentence, how can I ensure the `tooltip text` doesn't instantly vanish, when clicked on, via mobile?**

---

Update: I added the following javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.tooltipped').tooltip({delay: 100});
    $('.tooltipped').trigger('mouseleave');
    $('.tooltipped').trigger('needs click');
});
```

Currently, the first tooltip clicked on will open, but subsequent ones will exhibit vanishing text if the user *first* clicks away. If instead the user clicks on another tooltip, then they text will render properly :-/

Comment: Is 'hovering' a thing on mobile then?

Comment: ah, apologies, fixed the typo

Comment: I don't know if it's also a typo, but you're missing `-` in `data-tooltip`

Comment: And double quote after and before `data-tooltip=`.